# Effect pressed of a RelativeLayout when i have image

Tags: android, android-listview

Sorry for my English... this is a Google traductor.

I am following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

My problem is with the background image .. In my case it is not a color but an image of the sdcard. Works fine. But I want that image to darken when I click on the item and return to its original color when I release the item

I know I can put another image edited with photoshop for example and follow the tutorial, but then would have to create many images, much time and weight of the apk. Maybe with a few lines of code could be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using **ImageButton**, you can try this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    ...
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/your_description" />
```

Then in your Java code you add this:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
button.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

And this is the code that make your image darken (in this case is brighten, so is up to you to find the correct color):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // Apply the pressed effect on a button
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) v;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 155, 155, 155));
        return false;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 155, 155, 155));
        return false;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Try it and let me know!

Comment: @user1959076 glad to help you, don't forget to accept your answer :) !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **ImageView** , try using **ImageButton**

Answer (score 0):

Thats its the code

```
        Resources res = vi.getResources();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getRutaImagen());
        final BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);

        // ----------------------------------
        final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 155, 155, 155));
                    Log.d("aaa","DOWN");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 155, 155, 155));
                    Log.d("aaa","UP");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I get the "DOWN" and "UP" but the imagebutton dont change...

```
android:clickable="true"
```

This code dont extends of Activity... extends of BaseAdapter